# Casting an enum to it's underlying type doesn't satisfy my function signature

Tags: c++, enums

I've got a function that looks like this...

```
void get_u16(const char *const key, uint16_t &output) {
    ...stuff goes here
}
```

And an enum that looks like this...

```
struct MyEnum {
  typedef enum : uint16_t {
    FOO = 0,
    BAR = 1,
  } Type;
};
```

And I'm trying to call my function like so...

```
MyEnum::Type thingy = MyEnum::BAR;
get_u16("some key", (uint16_t)thingy);
```

And it's complaining to me saying...

```
/project/components/Data/Data.cpp:498:77: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'uint16_t&' {aka 'short unsigned int&'} to an rvalue of type 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'}
```

I'm confused. The underlying type of my enum is `uint16_t` and I'm even trying to cast it to that type in my method call. Is there some way I can say "Hey C++, I swear you can trust me. Treat this as a uint16_t." in a way where C++ will play along?

Comment: Putting your direct issue aside, why are you nesting a typedef inside a struct? Why not use `enum class` or `enum struct`?

Comment: Upvoted as the question is clear, and as I have already commented, this is a bewildering error when you first encounter it. Some earlier compilers allowed binding of temporaries to references without even a warning, and this flavour of C-style casts produces an rvalue.

Comment: @Victor thank you for introducing me to `enum class`! That's a cleaner way to get the enum behavior I like!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(uint16_t)thingy` is an *rvalue*, it's a temporary value that will disappear as soon as the full expression is finished. C++ doesn't allow you to bind *lvalue* references to rvalues.

Either you need to make the argument an rvalue reference:

```
void get_u16(const char *const key, uint16_t &&output)
```

Or you need to use constant references:

```
void get_u16(const char *const key, uint16_t const &output)
```

Or use a variable that you pass instead:

```
uint16_t my_var = thingy;
get_u16("some key", my_var);
```

Answer (score 2):

`(uint16_t)thingy` is an *anonymous temporary* and therefore a non-`const` reference cannot bind to it.

`void get_u16(const char *const key, const uint16_t &output) {`

is a fix. Another possibility is

`void get_u16(const char *const key, const uint16_t &&output) {`

as an *r-value reference* is a suitable binding.

Comment: ah, get FGITW'd. anyways, [links](https://godbolt.org/z/o1edqGvoz) to prove that it works.

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine: This is a bewildering error when you first encounter it. Some earlier compilers allowed binding of temporaries to references without even a warning, and this flavour of C-style casts produces an rvalue.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Added the second possibility as by some coincidence, I've just made use of it in my codebase ;-)